# Video Games - Who Am I?

Tags: riddle, video-games

I have three puzzles about video games. It's OK if you just answer one or two puzzles, but its better if you answer all of them. Your answers must contain your reasons. Here you go:

**Game 1**

My name consists of `two words`. You can find me in a latest funny song. Too long, and that thing will be broken by time. Only at that time, you will find me in two colors. My authorization is in hell. Only those people who have special ability will be able to get free from my hell. I was born by my creator in a country where the sun rose for the first time.

**Game 2**

My name consists of `two words`. There are many stories end in my world, but you must oppose one same power: the big fire. Whichever happens, all events in my world can create many kinds of paradox, which create many other worlds; but that's the story for my sibling. End of my world happens at the same year as your world, when you're afraid of the inability of your magic machine to overcome the future.

**Game 3**

My name is `the shortest among my friends' name`. The main character in my world is an unexpected one; if you do it right, you can reveal its true identity. In this phase, I'm the first power which uses a series of keywords so you can continue exploring my world. My name isn't the name of the main character; my name is the name of the creature in my world. It can suck your power in a second. You can defeat it only when it can't move.

Comment: Welcome to puzzling

Comment: Is there any connection between the three answers? If not, this might be better as three entirely separate questions.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan No, they aren't connected. Except for the **Game 3**, which says `the name is the shortest`

Comment: Game 3 actually says "shortest among my friends' name" - and the puzzle doesn't indicate the "friends" are the subjects of the other games.  So you are saying that Game 3's speaker's name is shorter than the names of the speakers of the other two games?  (Rather than, say, shorter than the names of the in-Game-3 friends of the Game 3 subject?)

Comment: @Rubio You must find it yourself, whether it is the speaker name or the game title name :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer:

Game 2 is:

> Chrono Trigger. The game has many endings, but all revolve around defeating Lavos (a huge alien that plunged into Earth in a ball of fire). The main mechanic of the game involves actions that affect changes in alternate timelines. A sequel, Chrono Cross, explores the same cause-and-effect cycle. In Chrono Trigger, Lavos awakens and ends the world in 1999 A.D. (pretty close to what we once thought would be Doomsday).

Comment: How about the magic machine?

Comment: @GraceMichelle: oh darn. I'm wrong, aren't I?

Comment: I didn't say that you are wrong. Can't you explain the magic machine?

Comment: I do remember a few machines, but it's been so long since I played that I can't be sure which you refer to. Even a quick wiki of the game in question didn't help me. Sorry...

Comment: It's OK. Your answer is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Game 1

> No idea here, the only hint that I can even remotely understand is the last one and seems to mean the game was made in Japan. As for the getting out of hell thing might refer to a survival game such as Resident Evil or Silent Hill. But I have little hope of those to be the correct ones.

Game 2

> I think game 2 is chrono trigger for most of the reasons already give by Xenocacia plus I would suppose that epoch is the magic machine(or the mamon machine) and that chrono cross is the sibling that was caused by the paradox. the end of the world occur in the end 2000 in the game which is about the real time in our world now.

Game 3

> I think game 3 is undertale. The real name of the hero is only revealed at the end of 1 of the perfect playthrough. The final fight boss dodge all your attacks until he stop moving then die in 1 hit. Dam Sans!

Comment: For Game 3, can you explain the power of the creature?

Comment: Are you referring to the final fight of genocide route? Which the power would be poison like effect every time you get hit that stacks and drain all your health over time?

Comment: I was referring to my puzzle above at line 4: in this phase... Please explain that power

Comment: Then you referring to DETERMINATION! and the keywords being LVL EXP which the meanings has been twisted to awful meanings in this game? XD

Comment: Yes, explain it

Comment: explain....even more? Should I describe the whole game? XD Determination is just that determination, which might be seen as the will of never giving up which is seen as the power to reload from save everytime you lose, which is referenced too many times in the game. EXP stands for execution points, LVL stands for LOVE which stands for Level of Violence.

Comment: Your answers for Game 2 & 3 are correct :)

Comment: But sorry, I can't upvote you now, because of my rep. And I accept Xenocacia's answer because it's the first correct answer. I'll upvote you later :)

Comment: I'm not so sure my answer should have been accepted when I only got 1 of 3 games right. Thanks anyway but if you can rescind it and save it for someone more deserving, you really should.

Answer (score 0):

Well then, seems Game 1 is still open. Let me take a stab:

My name consists of two words.

> Demon's Souls

You can find me in a latest funny song.
Too long, and that thing will be broken by time.

> No clue here...

Only at that time, you will find me in two colors.

> Upon Death the game fades to black & white

My authorization is in hell.

> Demons

Only those people who have special ability will be able to get free from my hell.

> It and the not-sequels it spawned are notoriously difficult.

I was born by my creator in a country where the sun rose for the first time.

> Japan, land of the rising sun

Comment: Sorry, that's not the right answer :)

Comment: @GraceMichelle Aw. Thanks for telling me though.

Answer (score 0):

**Game 1:**

> Pokémon Go

The song

> The funny song that went viral could be the one that goes "I play pokémon go everyday".

"you will find me in two colors"

> Pokémon games often comes in two colors (ex: red/green)

"I was born by my creator in a country where the sun rose for the first time."

> It makes me think of Japan and Pokémon was created in Japan.

**Game 2:**

Xenocacia already found the answer

> which is Chrono Trigger.

I would have guessed

> Dark Souls

"There are many stories end in my world, but you must oppose one same power: the big fire"

> Dark Souls lore and story is focused around rekindling the fire. Unfortunatly the other elements of the puzzle didn't really make sense.

**Game 3:**

> Metroid

"The main character in my world is an unexpected one"

> The main character is a female, Samus Aran. It was quite the shock when people finished the game for the first time.

"if you do it right, you can reveal its true identity"

> Beating the game 100% and fast enough will unlock the ending where Samus gets out of her power suit revealing her face (or more), showing her true identity.

"I'm the first power which uses a series of keywords so you can continue exploring my world"

> Metroid had a list of passwords which were the old way of "saving" your progress in the game.

"My name isn't the name of the main character; my name is the name of the creature in my world."

> People often call Samus Aran "Metroid",but the Metroids are hostile npc in the game.

"It can suck your power in a second. You can defeat it only when it can't move."

> Metroids suck the life force out of their preys. They can be defeated by using ice missiles which stop them from moving (being frozen).